# stackLabels with separate data in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts, stacked-chart, drilldown

Good afternoon, I'm putting together a chart that uses Highcharts stackLabels, it's exactly the same as this: JSFiddle however I do not want it to display the sum of the column values, I want it to appear item by item one on top of the other, same as the print I simulated below:

[image: Simulation...]

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/yaxis/stacklabels-style/

Comment: [FAQ on how to question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)
and [Make it Minimal, Complete and Verfiable Example(MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to set your `stackLabels` as you expecting, you need to use `stackLabels.formatter` function to calculate the labels values manually.

Next thing you've to do is make a little shifting on the labels. You are able to do it by `stackLabels.y` field.

At the end, don't forget about the `stackLabels.useHTML` parameter set equal to `true`. It makes the `<span>` and `</br>` elements will appear correctly. Please take a look at code below:

```
yAxis: {
  stackLabels: {
    style: {
      color: 'red'
    },
    enabled: true,
    useHTML: true,
    formatter: function() {
      var firstLabel = Math.round((this.points[0][1] - this.points[0][0]) * 10) / 10,
        secondLabel = this.points[0][0]

      return `<span>${firstLabel}</span></br>
              <span>${secondLabel}</span>`
    },
    y: -15
  }
}
```

You can read more about parameters mentioned above here:

- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.stackLabels.formatter
- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.stackLabels.y
- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.stackLabels.useHTML

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/r01nkgyn/

Comment: And if it's 3 data in the column, how would I have to do the thirdLabel?

Comment: @Medina, when there is a three data points in a stack you can just add another variable equal to `points[1][0]`, show it in returning string and increase `y` value to make bigger shift of labels. Here is the example: http://jsfiddle.net/vbqaa2g2/

Comment: but the secondLabel is showing the sum value of it with the thirdLabel

Comment: You're right, my mistake. Here is the correct formula - `this.points[1][1] - this.points[1][0]` and live example: http://jsfiddle.net/vbqaa2g2/1/